# Volume of a solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid in $\Bbb R^3$, bounded by
$$y = x^2\\x=y^2\\z=x+y+30\\z=0
$$
For me setting the integral is the issue!

Comment: Do you know what it looks like?

Comment: No I do not know how it looks like!

Comment: Try to draw a picture of these objects. What are they? (lines, points, surfaces, solids?)

Comment: I tried to get the right picture for it but I am really lost! and I I was not lost why I am here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

$$V = \int\int\int_D dV$$

$$dV = dzdydx$$

The limits are $$ 0<=z <= x+y+30 = x+y+30$$
$$x^{2}<=y<=\sqrt{x}$$

$$x=y^2, y = x^2, x = x^4 =>    x(x^{3}-1) =0 => x=0 or x = 1, 0<=x<=1$$

$$V = \int_0^1 \int_{{x^2}}^{\sqrt{x}} \int_0^{x+y+30} dz dy dx$$

Comment: What is the function that I am integrating?

Comment: I thought that it is just 1 and i got 604/16 but it is not rhe write answer

Comment: It is the volume bounded by a plane and curves.

Comment: yeah but I mean what is f(x,y,z) ??

Comment: The volume V of the solid that lies below the surface $z = z_{top} = z_{2}(x, y)$ and above the surface $z = z_{bottom} = z_{1}(x, y)$ is (assuming that this integral exists)$$V =\int \int_R
[z_{top} − z_{bottom}]dA $$. $$\int \int_R [z_{2}(x, y) − z_{1}(x, y)]dA$$.

Comment: I got 12.2857 and it is wrong, can you help me please to get the right answer

Comment: What is the answer given in the book?

Comment: It is not from a book it is an online homework!

Comment: I got it right now thanks